# SimpleHypergraphs.jl - loading hypergraph from text file

Tags: julia, network-analysis, hypergraph

I'm using the SimpleHypergraphs.jl library and trying to construct a hypergraph from a text file such as a csv.

For example, I'd like to load a hypergraph from a csv file like this:

```
0.0, 7.0, 0.0, 0.0
1.3, 2.8, 4.5, 0.0
0.0, 1.3, 3.1, 4.2
1.2, 0.0, 5.6, 5.0
```

```
using SimpleHypergraphs
using CSV

df = CSV.read("edge_weights.csv", DataFrame)
m = Matrix{Float64}(df)
h = Hypergraph(m)
```

I receive the following error:
"ERROR: MethodError: no method matching Hypergraph(::Matrix{Float64})"

I'm new to Julia and I would really appreciate an example of how I could accomplish this. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The matrix that is passed as a `Hypergraph` constructor should have elements of type `Union{Nothing, T}` where  `T` is some numeric type (e.g. `Matrix{Union{Float64,Nothing}}` rather than just be a `Matrix{Float64}`.

In SimpleHypegraphs.jl, we use `nothing` (rather than `0`) to represent that a vertex does not belong to a hyperedge since in many hypergraph algorithms/applications it is possible for a vertex to belong  to a hyper-edge with a zero weight.

Hence you could read your file with the following code (for reproducibility I put the file content into a text variable):

```
using DataFrames, CSV, SimpleHypergraphs

txt = """0.0, 7.0, 0.0, 0.0
1.3, 2.8, 4.5, 0.0
0.0, 1.3, 3.1, 4.2
1.2, 0.0, 5.6, 5.0"""

df = CSV.read(IOBuffer(txt), DataFrame;header=0)

mat = Matrix{Union{Float64,Nothing}}(df)
```

This matrix can now easily be used as a `Hypergraph` constructor.

```
julia> h1 = Hypergraph(mat)
4×4 Hypergraph{Float64, Nothing, Nothing, Dict{Int64, Float64}}:
 0.0  7.0  0.0  0.0
 1.3  2.8  4.5  0.0
 0.0  1.3  3.1  4.2
 1.2  0.0  5.6  5.0
```

However, this might be not exactly what you need because zeros (`0.0`) represent a situation where vertices belong to hyperedges with zero weights:

```
draw(h1, HyperNetX)
```

[image]

Hence, you might actually want to convert zeros to `nothing`s to represent situation where the vertices do not belong to hyperedges:

```
h2 = Hypergraph(replace(mat, 0 => nothing))
```

Now you get what you wanted:

```
draw(h2, HyperNetX)
```

[image]